# How do I upload DATETIME data with DolphinDB Python API

Tags: python, datetime, dolphindb

I was trying to upload some DATETIME data with DolphinDB Python API. I tried the following code.

```
from datetime import datetime
import dolphindb as ddb

sess = ddb.session('localhost', 8848)
sess.upload({'t': datetime(2020, 2, 2)})
```

But I got the following exception.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "/home/ynwang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dolphindb/session.py", line 64, in upload
>
> return self.cpp.upload(nameObjectDict)
>
> RuntimeError: unrecognized Python type:

So how do I correctly upload the datetime data?

Answer (score 1):

I believe DolphinDB Python API only supports numpy.datetime64. Try the following script:

```
sess.upload({'t':np.datetime64(datetime(2020,2,2))})
```